# WaitingForActivation instead of key vault secret value (in Azure), why?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-keyvault, secret-key, azure-managed-identity

I am trying to connect to my Key Vault using Manged Identity in Azure. 
For this I have added an entry with key vault name in appsettings.json, under KeyVault, under Vault.
I also made the following changes to my Program.cs, basically added a variable of type `IConfiguration` to help me read my `appsettings.json` and the whole ConfigureAppConfiguration part.

```
public IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }

public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration(builder =>
        {
            // use Identity Management
            var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appsettings.json").Build();
            var keyVaultUrl = string.Format("https://{0}.vault.azure.net/", configuration.GetSection("KeyVault").GetSection("Vault").Value);

            var azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
            var keyVaultClient = new KeyVaultClient(
                new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(
                    azureServiceTokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback));
            builder.AddAzureKeyVault(keyVaultUrl, keyVaultClient, new DefaultKeyVaultSecretManager());

            var secretValue = keyVaultClient.GetSecretAsync(keyVaultUrl, "MyApp-MyDatabaseSettings--MyDatabasePassword");
        })
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        });
```

When I hover over secretValue , I get a status `WaitingForActivation` (instead of actual value), any idea why?

***Edit: I did go to the web app > Identity > System assigned > and set it to ON.***

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by doing this:

```
var secretVal = Task.Run(async () => await keyVaultClient.GetSecretAsync(keyVaultUrl, "MyApp-MyDatabaseSettings--MyDatabasePassword")).Result.Value;
```

I will keep this open to other answers, in case someone knows a better way.

PS. If you still have problems after this, might want to check if you have multiple accounts associated with your Visual Studio, go to Tools - Options - search Azure - switch to the right account that you have logged into azure cli. And also to complete the setup, with that email address also go to your keyvault and "add new policy" with Get, List permissions for secrets and add also that email address as Select principal...

Answer (score 0):

> any idea why?

Because the `GetSecretAsync` method is asynchronous and returns a `Task<T>` to be awaited. A `Task<T>` in .NET represents an asynchronous operation that *eventually* returns a value.

You should await the `GetSecretAsync` method but since there is no overload of `ConfigureAppConfiguration` that accepts a `Func<IConfigurationBuilder, Task>` instead of an `Action<IConfigurationBuilder>`, you need to this in an `async` method that returns a `Task` or `Task<T>` before or after `CreateDefaultBuilder` is called.

Or you could access the `Result` property to block synchronously:

```
var secretVal = keyVaultClient.GetSecretAsync(keyVaultUrl, 
   "MyApp-MyDatabaseSettings--MyDatabasePassword").Result;
```

This is at least better than using `Task.Run` to start a new `Task` to execute the asynchronous method on a background thread and then block this thread like you are currently doing.